# update android studio will erase all my project?

Tags: android, android-studio

sorry to ask a silly question here. Will all my project get erased if I update `android studio` to latest version? Thanks

Comment: No, but i recommend you to make a copy of your workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not. You can update studio without worrying about it.

Answer (score 0):

It will not delete any of your project, you can update it and don't worry ...

Answer (score 0):

For the safety reason, recommend you copy your workspace first.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will be fine. If you want to be extra safe you should install Git and push your project files to GitHub. [install Git here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)