# Android Studio Update what will happen to the existing project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Sorry for the silly questions but I will be updating Android Studio 2.3.2 to Android 3.5 (newest version) I am in worry because of the gradle files that can get corrupted after the update. I am using Ubuntu. Can I update without worries? My project uses Firebase, Google Maps as Google Apis. Having a copy of the workspace is done. Do I need to do anything else before updating?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? You will be worried in any case.

Comment: Well, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647969/update-android-studio-will-erase-all-my-project

Comment: As long as you version control your project you shouldn't worry. A lot of things might break due to changes in gradle and AS but nothing that would prevent you from finally building and further developing your project.